# Error when installing resque brain on centos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, centos, gemfile

I am trying to install resque brain (https://github.com/stitchfix/resque-brain) on my vm machine which runs centos. When I run 'rake test' I get the following error.

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: compile error - syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'spring',        group: :development
                           ^. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /root/user/resque-brain/Gemfile:11
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
 >  gem 'spring',        group: :development
 #  gem 'bower-rails'
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions how I might be able to fix this? I tried so far to update ruby and buddle.

```
# bundle -v
Bundler version 1.10.6

# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: I already formatted your question once. If you update it, please stop breaking the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Gemfile` file syntax is based on Ruby 1.9 as it uses the json-style syntax.

```
group: :development
```

You use Ruby 1.8.7, therefore you must rewrite it into

```
:group => :development
```

Please note you are using a very old version of Ruby which is buggy, outdated, slow and most importantly no longer supported.

You should upgrade your Ruby version before proceeding, as this one will likely not be the only issue you will encounter. I'm not even sure that `Rescue` and associated libraries are still compatible with Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.8 doesn't support JSON-style hashes. So try `gem 'spring', :group => :development` or just

```
group :development do
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: What is `JSON-style` hashes ?

Comment: @Зелёный, `group: :development` is JSON-style (which is available since Ruby 1.9), and `:group => :development` is the old style (Ruby 1.8)